# Highly composite number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

**Definition**: n is said to be a highly composite number if and only if $d(n)>d(m)$ for all $m<n$, where $d(n)$ denotes number of divisors of n.

**Questions**:
1) Are there any theorems about highest prime that divides n, assuming that n is highly composite?. It seems that the highest prime is of the order of ln(n).
2) Are there any theorems about the highest power of 2 which divides n, assuming that n is highly composite?

Comment: Have you checked out the references in OEIS?  There are quite a few.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1944-056-00/S0002-9947-1944-0011087-2/S0002-9947-1944-0011087-2.pdf) by Alaoglu and Erdős proves that if $p$ is the largest prime divisor of a highly composite number (HCN) $n$ then the exponent $k_q$ on another prime $q$ dividing
$n$ satisfies 
$$\log\left(1 + \frac{1}{k_q}\right) > \frac{\log q \log 2}{\log p} + O\left(\frac{(\log \log p)^3}{(\log p)^3}\right),$$
$$\log\left(1 + \frac{1}{k_q+1}\right) < \frac{\log q \log 2}{\log p} + O\left(\frac{(\log \log p)^3}{(\log p)^3}\right).$$
(See Theorem 12.)

For sufficiently large $q$ they claim that $k_q$ is either $\Lambda$, $\Lambda + 1$, or $\Lambda - 1$, where $$\Lambda = \left\lfloor \left(2^{\log q/\log p} - 1\right)^{-1} \right\rfloor.$$  (See Theorem 13.)

When $q = 2$ this latter formula appears to be close, although it is not exactly correct, as there are more than three possible values for the power of 2 that divides a highly composite number with largest prime factor $p$.  See, for example, [this list of the first 1200 HCN's](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/highly.txt), which includes their prime factorizations.

This, together with Derek Jennings' answer on the order of $p$, should give you the estimate of the highest power of 2 that divides $n$.

Answer (score 5):

In this paper [On Highly Composite Numbers](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1944-04.pdf) P. Erdős uses Bertrand's postulate and the Prime Number Theorem to show that if $p$ is the highest prime that divides $n,$ a highly composite number, then

$$ c_1 \log n < p < c_2 \log n $$

for some constants $c_1$ and $c_2 .$

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot to know that there is formal proof of what I expected.